# Smallest sum of triplet products where the middle element is removed using Dynamic Programming

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

I have given a sequence of N numbers (4 ≤ N ≤ 150). One index i (0 < i < N) is picked and multiplied with the left and the right number, in other words with i-1 and i+1. Then the i-th number is removed. This is done until the sequence has only two numbers left over. The goal is to find the smallest sum of these products which obviously depends on the order in which the indices are picked.

E.g. for the sequence 44, 45, 5, 39, 15, 22, 10 the smallest sum would be 17775
using the indices in the following order: 1->3->4->5->2 which is the sum:
44*45*5 + 5*39*15 + 5*15*22 + 5*22*10 + 44*5*10 = 9900 + 2925 + 1650 + 1100 + 2200 = 17775

I have found a solution using a recursive function:

```
public static int smallestSum(List<Integer> values) {
    if (values.size() == 3)
        return values.get(0) * values.get(1) * values.get(2);
    else {
        int ret = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int i = 1; i < values.size() - 1; i++) {
            List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<Integer>(values);
            copy.remove(i);

            int val = smallestSum(copy) + values.get(i - 1) * values.get(i) * values.get(i + 1);
            if (val < ret) ret = val; 
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

However, this solution is only feasible for small N but not for a bigger amount of numbers. What I am looking for is a way to do  this using an iterative Dynamic Programming approach.

Answer (score 3):

The optimal substructure needed for a DP is that, given the identity of the last element removed, the elimination strategy for the elements to the left is independent of the elimination strategy for the elements to the right. Here's a new recursive function (`smallestSumA`, together with the version from the question and a test harness comparing the two) incorporating this observation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (int n = 3 + r.nextInt(8); n > 0; n--) {
        values.add(r.nextInt(100));
      }
      int a = smallestSumA(values, 0, values.size() - 1);
      int q = smallestSumQ(values);
      if (q != a) {
        System.err.println("oops");
        System.err.println(q);
        System.err.println(a);
        System.err.println(values);
      }
    }
  }

  public static int smallestSumA(List<Integer> values, int first, int last) {
    if (first + 2 > last)
      return 0;
    int ret = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = first + 1; i <= last - 1; i++) {
      int val = (smallestSumA(values, first, i)
          + values.get(first) * values.get(i) * values.get(last) + smallestSumA(values, i, last));
      if (val < ret)
        ret = val;
    }
    return ret;
  }

  public static int smallestSumQ(List<Integer> values) {
    if (values.size() == 3)
      return values.get(0) * values.get(1) * values.get(2);
    else {
      int ret = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      for (int i = 1; i < values.size() - 1; i++) {
        List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<Integer>(values);
        copy.remove(i);

        int val = smallestSumQ(copy) + values.get(i - 1) * values.get(i) * values.get(i + 1);
        if (val < ret)
          ret = val;
      }

      return ret;
    }
  }
}
```

Invoke as `smallestSum(values, 0, values.size() - 1)`.

To get the DP, observe that there are only `N choose 2` different settings for `first` and `last`, and memoize. The running time is `O(N^3)`.

Comment: This doesn't work because it doesn't consider element removal properly. E.g the provided example sequence outputs 37770 because  when we start with i=1 in the first iteration of the recursive call values[i-1] will be equal to values[i] for the caller because the recursive call will be invoked with first=i=1 and therefore the loop will start with first+1=2 so values[i-1] in the recursive call is equal to values[i]. Actually the i-th element may not appear in the recursive call so it has to be removed from the array or it must be ignored otherwise, e.g. by keeping track of removed elements.

Comment: @user538331 Fixed a bug where I used `i-1` and `i+1` instead of `first` and `last`. The revised version appears to be correct.

Comment: Thanks this works. I think I should be able to get the rest myself

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in a DP solution, based on David Eisenstat's recursive solution, here is an iterative one using DP (for many big numbers it's useful to replace int's with long's):

```
public static int smallestSum(List<Integer> values) {
    int[][] table = new int[values.size()][values.size()];

    for (int i = 2; i < values.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j + i < values.size(); j++) {
            int ret = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            for (int k = j + 1; k <= j + i - 1; k++) {
                int val = table[j][k] + values.get(j) * values.get(k) * values.get(j + i) + table[k][j + i];
                if (val < ret) ret = val;
            }

            table[j][j + i] = ret;
        }
    }

    return table[0][values.size() - 1];
}
```